# The derivative of the Heaviside step function in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Here is a problem I have:

Consider the Heaviside function
$$H(x)=H(x_1)H(x_2)\cdots H(x_n), ~~~x\in\mathbb{R}^n$$
and prove that
$$\dfrac{\partial^n H(x)}{\partial x_1\partial x_2\cdots\partial x_n}=\delta(x)$$
where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac's delta function.

I know $H'(x)=\delta(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, but here $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ how can I proceed for the $nth$ partial derivative of $H(x)$? Any help?

Comment: What is your definition of $\delta(\mathbf x)$ for $\mathbf x\in\mathbb R^n$, i.e. in higher dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:
$$\frac{\partial^n H(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_1\cdots \partial x_n} = \frac{\operatorname d H(x_1)}{\operatorname d x_1}\cdots \frac{\operatorname d H(x_n)}{\operatorname d x_n} = \delta(x_1)\cdots \delta(x_n),$$
which is the product of one-dimensional Delta distributions.

Comment: Yes! thanking you. This follows from the definition of $\delta(x)$, for $x\in R^n$.